# How to prevent this dling/sql error - or is it because bad network?

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, dynamic-linq

Step 1)
I check that i can acess server: 
(because i have offline handling to)

```
public static bool dbOnline(string timeOut="3")
{
  bool online = false;
       try
       {
           var testConn = new SqlConnection(Utils.ConnectionStr(timeOut)); 
           testConn.Open();
           online = true;
           testConn.Close();
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           online = false;
       }
       return online;
   }
```

2) It returns ok, then i Create dlinq instance !

```
_DataContext = new DataContext(Utils.ConnectionStr);//System.Data.Linq.DataContext
//then i point out a customer in DB

var customer = _DataContext.Customers.TableQuery().FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == custid);

//Check its not null
if (customer != null)
{
            customer.points+= _points;
            customer.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            customer.SubmitChanges();
}
```

3) And sometimes i get this error, is it anything i can do to prevent this, or is it to
fix the network? (i know there is some trouble with the network), but can i do anything
different?  - Thanks

**Error:
**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.****

```
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicUpdate(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Update(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timeout is impossible to identify in isolation, however I would usually expect a **network** error to have a different error. The things I'd look at first:

- is the data indexed correctly
- was there blocking at the time, most likely by a long-running transaction that has a lock on the data
- was there anything like a db grow happening at the time
- was the server exceptionally busy at the time

My money would be on the second

Also, we can't see what `TableQuery()` is; if that returns `IEnumerable<Customer>`, then it could be related to pulling too much data (in your context, it should probably be returning `IQueryable<Customer>` at the minumum, but we can't see).

The real thing to do here is to run a SQL trace and try to catch it in the act - see what was happening.

Comment: ah. IQueryable<TEntity> TableQuery() - yes, IQueryable. - Yes the data is from an microsoft standard database.

Comment: (this is after an transaction) From the time I create the datacontext, to i do the addpoints,, its not mutch time between them.

Comment: The server is busy but, i have clients(Same app) in another country to the same server and there is no error.

Comment: @Niklas re your second bullet; the issue is with **other** clients

Comment: ? re your second bullet; the issue is with other clients - huh? :) what do you mean? (the other clients have another Databas but on the same server)

Comment: @Niklas you mean this one connection is the only thing talking to that entire database?

Comment: No - the database is Quity Busy.. But from this app, it the only connection.

Comment: @Niklas exactly; anything else touching that table has the potential to cause locks, especially if a transaction or large update is involved

Comment: OK thanks - but why does it say timeout? Thanks anyway - but what can you do to prevent a locks like you describe?

Comment: @Niklas because locking is the most common way of delaying a command's completion, and if it takes too long to complete, that is a timeout by definition. Re preventing locks: depends on things like isolation level, transactions, etc